# How do you get a newly started Activity to announce itself in Android TalkBack?

Tags: android, android-activity, talkback

How do you get a newly started Activity to announce itself in Android TalkBack?

All the documentation I can find only refers to Views, not Activities, and those Views only announce themselves when touched. What I need is, on a change of Activity, some spoken text to tell the user where they are in the app hierarchy. Right now, on every Activity change, TalkBack just states the app name every time, which isn't useful.

I've tried adding contentDescription to the root Layout element in the Activities layout XML, but that didn't seem to make any difference. Example:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:contentDescription="My new Activity"
>
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `android:label` attribute on the `Activity` tag in your `AndroidManifest`.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks kcoppock. I tried 'contentDescription' in the manifest, but although valid, it didn't use the text, but 'label' works fine. Would be be nice to know if that's documented somewhere - or you found out by trial and error. Cheers...

Comment: I happened to notice it while working on something else, but it may be documented somewhere.

Comment: I'd like to know how to override that at run time.

Comment: At runtime you can just call setTitle on the Activity.